# How to join two objects to share values but maintain the original name? Aka N-body merger

Tags: python, object, pygame, simulation, physics

As the title says, I am working on an N-body simulation I found on YouTube. The current script has gravity turned off when radius is small enough. However, I'd like to join the two objects (body and otherbody) into a new one which behaves according to the same rules, it just has the properties of both added. How do I do this? Here is the code in question.

```py
import pygame
from sys import exit
import math as m
import itertools
import random

pygame.init()
WINDOW_SIZE = (1500,1500)
WINDOW = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE)
CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
G=1

BACKGROUND = pygame.Surface(WINDOW_SIZE)
BACKGROUND.fill("Black")
BACKGROUND_RECT = BACKGROUND.get_rect(center=(500,500))

class Body(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, mass, radius, init_position, color, vx, vy):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.image = pygame.Surface([(radius*2),(radius*2)])
        self.image.fill("Black")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=init_position)
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, color, (radius,radius), radius, 0)
        
        self.mass = mass
        self.radius = radius
        self.x_pos = init_position[0]
        self.y_pos = init_position[1]
        
        self.vx = vx
        self.ax = 0
        self.vy = vy
        self.ay = 0
    
    def set_vy(self,value):
        self.vy = value
    def set_xv(self,value):
        self.vx = value
    def set_ay(self,value):
        self.ay = value
    def set_ax(self,value):
        self.ax=value
        
    def change_x_pos(self,value):
        self.x_pos+=value
    def change_y_pos(self,value):
        self.y_pos+=value
    def change_vx(self,value):
        self.vx+=value
    def change_vy(self,value):
        self.vy+=value
        
    def update_pos(self):
        self.rect.center = (round(self.x_pos), round(self.y_pos))
        
    def animate(self):
        self.change_vx(self.ax)
        self.change_vy(self.ay)
        
        self.change_x_pos(self.vx)
        self.change_y_pos(self.vy)
        
        self.update_pos()

    def gravity(self, otherbody):
        dx = self.x_pos - otherbody.x_pos
        dy = self.y_pos - otherbody.y_pos
        
        if dx < self.radius*2 and dy < self.radius*2:
            pass

        else:
            try:
                r = m.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)
                a = G*otherbody.mass/r**2
                theta = m.asin(dy/r)
        
                if self.y_pos > otherbody.y_pos:
                    self.set_ay(-m.sin(theta)*a)
                else:
                    self.set_ay(m.sin(theta)*a)
                
                if self.x_pos > otherbody.x_pos:
                    self.set_ax(-m.cos(theta)*a)
                else:
                    self.set_ax(m.cos(theta)*a)
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                pass


body_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
BODYCOUNT=3
for i in range(BODYCOUNT):
    body_group.add(Body(10, 3, (random.randrange(100,900), random.randrange(100,900)), "White", 0,0))
    
body_list = list(body_group)
body_pairs = list(itertools.combinations(body_list,2))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
    WINDOW.blit(BACKGROUND, BACKGROUND_RECT)
    
    body_group.draw(WINDOW)
    
    for body, otherbody in body_pairs:
        body.gravity(otherbody)
        otherbody.gravity(body)
        body.animate()
        otherbody.animate()
    
    pygame.display.update()
    CLOCK.tick(60)
```

The part in question is  `if dx < self.radius*2 and dy < self.radius*2: pass`

How do I join the objects body and otherbody into a new body?

Also the current version of the script only has one object being attracted to the other, not equal attraction. If you see why, can you point it out?

Comment: I supposed yes, I would like to combine the sprites. I would like the sprites to combine when they become close enough (as if they are gravitationally bound together). I would like them to behave normally like the other "body" sprites in this simulation, just bigger with a combined mass (which is the first parameter for the body class).

I am struggling with syntax and knowing how to search the right questions. I am new to OOP.

Comment: Do not include the solution in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition is wrong. You need to calculate and compare the square of the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance). Use [`pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) to remove the `otherbody` from all groups and increase the size and mass of the body by the size and mass of the `otherbody`. Additionally there are some problems in the function `gravity`, which can be simplified anyway.

```py
class Body(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def join(self, otherbody):
        dx = self.x_pos - otherbody.x_pos
        dy = self.y_pos - otherbody.y_pos  
        if (dx*dx + dy*dy) < self.radius*self.radius:
            otherbody.kill()
            self.mass += otherbody.mass
            self.radius = m.sqrt(self.radius**2 + otherbody.radius**2)
            self.image = pygame.Surface([(self.radius*2),(self.radius*2)])
            self.image.fill("Black")
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)
            pygame.draw.circle(self.image, self.color, (self.radius,self.radius), self.radius, 0)

    def gravity(self, otherbody): 
        dx = self.x_pos - otherbody.x_pos
        dy = self.y_pos - otherbody.y_pos
        r = m.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)  
        a = G*otherbody.mass/r**2
        self.set_ax(a * -dx / r)
        self.set_ay(a * -dy / r)
```

Since the objects in `body_group` can change, `body_pairs` must be regenerated in each frame. `animate` each body only once and join the bodies after moving.

```py
while True:
    # [...]

    body_list = list(body_group)
    body_pairs = list(itertools.combinations(body_list,2))
    for body, otherbody in body_pairs:
        body.gravity(otherbody)
        otherbody.gravity(body)
    for body in body_list:
        body.animate()
    for body, otherbody in body_pairs:
        body.join(otherbody)
```